# Apache Redirection

Tags: apache2

I am reasonable new to Linux, but I am trying to learn with help from a multi purpose HTPC/NAS/PVR.

It has the following web based apps:

- Plex - localhost:32400/web
- Deluge - localhost:8112
- TVHeadend - localhost:9981

I am after a way to create a LAN only facing site that can make these easier to access rather than having to remember the ports. For example plex.localhost, deluge.localhost or tv.localhost. Can anybody provide some advice on how I might go about achieving this?

Before anyone responds, I know I can use browser bookmarks, and yes, I could use Firefox or Chrome logins that sync these bookmarks across multiple devices, but I thought it would be a good way to learn something new. I typically use these apps via a VPN so that the machine does not end up exposed to the internet.

Would appreciate any help, even if it's pointing me to the right Apache terminology to research how to achieve this. It seems like it should be relatively simple because the content (web pages) are already there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 301 Redirect. Create an Apache virtualhost for plex.localhost, deluge.localhost and tv.localhost and have the below line for each:

```
Redirect 301 / http://localhost:32400/web
```

A finished virtualhost block could look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin you@mail.com
    ServerName plex.localhost

    Redirect 301 / http://localhost:32400/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have DNS or a hosts entry for http://plex.localhost/, Apache should 301 you to http://localhost:32400/web instead.